# Is the following true?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

We know that $f(f^{-1}(E))\subset E$ is true from Rudin, but is $f^{-1}(f(E))\subset E$ true? What about $f^{-1}(f(E))=E$

My first instinct is to say yes, as long as the continuous function $f$ is a bijection, else no.

Answer (score 1):

We have $E \subset f^{-1}(f(E))$, with a sufficient condition for equality being that $f$ is injective.

Note that a sufficient condition for $f(f^{-1}(E)) = E$ is that $f$ is surjective.

Answer (score 0):

We have $f^{-1} (f(E)) \supset E$. The way I like to think of this is that your set can get bigger when you take preimages. For example, if $f$ is the squaring map, and $E$ is a nonzero real number, then $f^{-1} (f(E))$ is $2$ points, only one of which you started with.